# How to cast text to bit(64) in Redshift? Use PostgreSQL expression in Redshift

Tags: casting, amazon-redshift

could you please help me to convert this expression in the PostgreSQL syntax to the Redshift syntax:

```
(('x'::text || lpad(md5('0036f392-c2bc-46d5-b413-cd7772bcd4a1'), 16, '0'::text)))::bit(64)::bigint
```

The result equals `-5735530232431975337` in PostgreSQL.
Redshift throws an error: "cannot cast type text to bit".

UPD
It seems like similar question was asked here [Hex string to integer conversion in Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888593/hex-string-to-integer-conversion-in-amazon-redshift)

Answer (score 1):

The strtol() function takes a string representation of a number in any base and converts it to a bigint.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STRTOL.html

I've used this to change md5() results into integers for summing and comparison.  I wrote this up in another answer here: [More efficient way of comparing two tables in Redshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72712098/more-efficient-way-of-comparing-two-tables-in-redshift/72775442#72775442)

Comment: Thanks, so basically `select strtol((lpad(md5('UUID string'), 16, '0')), 16)` does the same for some UUIDs. For example, for this value `0010f3c8-cbf7-49c7-986e-9716085448d5`. But for those UUIDs for which the Postgre expression returns a negative value, like `0061d649-1f3b-4478-bfea-09a1c6012bc0` redshift returns `9223372036854775807`, which seems to be the biggest integer value. Do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I expect so.  the md5() of the second string is fb85eb3458d660193e238cbd55628e97 which has a left most bit of 1 which in binary indicates a negative number.  However strtol() makes no such assumption.  You could create a CASE statement based on the first bit and do the right math but I expect there is another issue.  md5() returns a 128 bit value but BIGINT only hold a 64 bit value.  How are you preventing overflow?  I used a substring() to select a portion of the md5 value.

Comment: `lpad` will return a substring: "..if longer than the remaining length or specified length it will be truncated on the right."

Comment: Gotcha.  So one way to avoid the the signed vs unsigned bigint difference would be to truncate to 15 characters.  If the first bit isn't a 1 then both interpretations will be positive.